# How to see a class instance's string representation rather than its type in VSCode's watch panel?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, variables can be added to the watch panel; however, the value displayed for custom classes seems to be the type rather than the class instance's **str**(...) representation.

Consider this example:

```
class MyCustomObject(object):

    state = "I'm beautiful and comprehensive!"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state

instance = MyCustomObject()
print(instance)
```

If I add `instance` to the watch window, what I see is:

`instance: <__main__.MyCustomObject object at 0x0000000001234>`

But what I want to see is:

`instance: 'I'm beautiful and comprehensive!'`

How can I do this?

Comment: Your code works as expected in Python 3.10.2! Already tested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to user [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
class MyCustomObject(object):

    state = "I'm beautiful and comprehensive!"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "State is: {}".format(self.state.__str__())
```

Comment: Thank you! Coming from a C# background, defining __str__(...) seemed to be the closest thing to C#'s ToString() method. I realize now that __repr__(...) is probably the way to go in most cases.